# JSF - how to add child to h:head or to h:body with managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I am trying to test my managed bean to modify web page dynamically *([programmatically](http://www.bradchen.com/blog/2011/07/render-facelets-programmatically))*; Most of jsf examples show how to use binding to modify ui but what about the rest of the web page? The samples are showing how to get to the `UIViewRoot` which is usually located in `h:body` block but what about the `h:body` itself or the `h:head`?

So my question is... Is there a way using `FacesContext` to get `h:body` or `h:head` as parent components and add children to them right with managed bean or please advise of how to get **alike** effect using other ways?

Thanks

Comment: You can create all such elements in your xhtml and display/hide using a variable in managed bean

Comment: @VikasSachdeva I couldn't see any examples; could you provide more details pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewRoot` is represented by `<f:view>` tag. If you don't define it explicitly in your JSF page, then it is added implicitly.

> UIViewRoot which is usually located in h:body block

No, it is **not** inside the body, but by default surrounding the body and head. Like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
    <f:view> <!-- No need to define. Added implicitly here in ComponentTree -->
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        </h:head> 
        <h:body>    
            <h:outputText value="#{hello.message}"/>            
       </h:body>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

So if you obtain the UIViewRoot using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()` and ask for its children (`.getChildren()`), you will get a list of 4 elements:

1. `UIInstructions`: renders `<html>`opening tag
2. `UIOutput`: this is the `<h:head>`. Ask for `getChildren` again to obtain a `UIOutput` for the `<meta>` tag
3. `HtmlBody`: this is `h:body` apparently. Ask for `getChildren` to get `<h:outputText>`
4. `UIInstructions`: renders the `</html>` closing tag

> add children to them right with managed bean

Yes, in general you can use your ManagedBeans to manipulate the UIComponentTree (e.g. add item, then reload the page to show it). However, consider the [JSF lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) and processing order (you e.g. cannot add a child as first element to the body during render-phase, cause items were already processed).
Sample to add new element to body:

```
List<UIComponent> viewRootChildren = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren();
for(UIComponent child : viewRootChildren){
    if( child instanceof HtmlBody ){
        HtmlOutputText newText = new HtmlOutputText();
        newText.setValue("added dynamically");
        child.add(newText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting :) So the UIInstructions is the parent of both UIOutput and the HtmlBody?

Comment: No, even though `<html>` is parent of `<f:view>` and `<f:view>` is parent of `<h:head>`and `<h:body>`, this is not true for the UIComponentTree on Java side. Instead, all these 4 elements are on the same hierarchy-level (children of `UIViewRoot`). You can then again call `getChildren` on any of these 4 elements, where `UIInstructions` does not have further children (but renders html only). UIOutput and HtmlBody do have further children and you can manipulate them via Java.

Comment: I recommend to ignore `<html>` and `UIInstructions` for now. This is different from other tags to include the html-root-element. Your question was on how to obtain `h:head` and `h:body` (2nd and 3rd element), which can be done as described. Maybe just try to call `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren()` anywhere in your ManagedBean, set a breakpoint and debug/inspect to see the UIComponentTree.

Comment: Updated answer on how to add element to body.

Comment: I got it but what about the JSF lifecycle? I mean may I get the HtmlBody in encodeBegin(...) for example or which event to take?

Comment: `encodeBegin()` is called in the RenderResponse-phase. Adding a component programmatically in `encodeBegin()` of another component would probably not make much sense, because similar results could be achieved directly within your xhtml-page. But for the sake of learning/testing, you could do that. Remember to add the new component as child to any component which has not been rendered yet (e.g. a component at the end of the body).

Comment: Apart from that, the position where to add your code really depends on what you are trying to achieve. When you e.g. want to add a component after user clicks a button, you can stick to regular ManagedBean methods and reload (via ajax, not via browser refresh which will trigger a new GET request).

Comment: Manipulating the UIComponentTree is usually not required for standard applications. You should have an understanding of some JSF internals for that. I suggest reading on the [advanced JSF concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkmaa.html), incl lifecycle and custom components. Then come back and post another question if required or read existing posts, there are several on those topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can display/hide your JSF components using the `rendered` attribute.

Below is a sample -

```
<h:outputText value="Result = #{calculator.result}" rendered="#{calculator.result != null}"/>
```

Here, this element will be displayed in UI only if `calculator.result` is not `null` where `calculator` is the name of your `managedBean` and `result` is a variable inside that bean. You can change value of this variable in pre-render event or in AJAX call or in other events.

For more than one element, you can use `<h:panelGroup>` with `rendered` attribute.

Comment: Please find a 'duplicate'  of this... several dozens on StackOverflow and mark the questions as a duplicate of one of these.

Comment: No, I mean how to use FacesContext to create components programmatically :S Not the tags way. See the link I give in my question pls

Comment: I think it may not be feasible. However, the same effect you can achieve using rendered attribute.

Comment: The rendered attribute is about to be located in view as its child or similar; but what about the `h:head` itseld or `h:body` itself? I am not sure how to get to them so please give me a tip how to add child to head or body; if you an optimal way know please do share...